# How to use PHP to query a view and write edited data to an outfile

Tags: php, mariadb

**Goal:** Use php to read, parse, & edit and write data from a view into a pipe delimited outfile.

**Setup:** I have a view “my_view” that has 11 columns/fields.  I need data from the first 10 written to the pipe delimited file.

**Complicating Factor:**  The tenth field has a string of text that may contain many comma separated values or it may be blank

**Requirement:** Output a file that has data separated by exactly 26 pipes

**My conceptual solution:**  Use php to query the view and return the table with fields separated by commas, then find and replace all commas with pipes.  Then calculate to ensure that each record/row has a total of 26 pipes even if there is no data to separate.

[I am using nuBuilder and can attach php to a button to initiate an action.  I will attach this code to be executed by the button in nubuilder.  I am able how to insert the code in nubuilder when I figure out how to write the php]

I've attempted solving this as a stored procedure in phpMyadmin but I can't seem to dynamically calculate out the required number of pipes.

My view (which I want the data from) looks like this:

```
Select
  Signals.SignalName
  Signals.SddName
  Signals.Address
  Signals.Word
  Signals.MSB
  Signals.LSB
  Signals.Resolution
  Signals.DataType
  Signals.Units
  Enumerations.TypeName (This is the column containing string of data        seperated by colums.
  Signals.FK_EnuID
  WHERE Signals FK_EnuID = Enumeratiopns.ID
```

I think I've come up with the following code:

```
<?php
$servername='localhost';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'database';

//Create a connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_view";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if (result->num_rows > 0) {
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

//string replace commas with pipes
$data = str_replace (',', '|', $row);

//Count number of pipes
$fields = substr_count($row, '|');

//Calculate the number of empty fields & insert pipes
$emptyfields = str_repeat('$|', (26-$fields));

//concatenate data with empty fields
$data .= $emptyfields;

//write data to file
file_put_contents (signals.dat, $data);
 }//end while
}
else{
      echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Comment: Take a look at CONCAT_WS https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$servername = 'myserver';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$dbname = 'mydb';

//create a connection
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname, 3306);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_view";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$rowcount = 0;
$filecount = 1;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
//build logic for splitting file.
$rowcount = $rowcount +1;

if (($rowcount % 10000)==)){
  $filecount = $filecount +1;

//join row elements into a string
$rowstr = join(","$row);

//String Replace commas with Pipes
$rowstr2 = str_replace(',', '|', $rowstr);

//Count number of Pipes
$fields = substr_count($rowstr2, '|');

//Calculate the number of empty fields & insert pipes
$emptyfields = str_repeat('|', 26-$fields));

//Concatenate data with empty fields
$rowstr2 .= $emptyfields;
$rowstr2 .= PHP_EOL;
$filename = 'signals_'.$filecount.'.dat';

//Write data to file
file_put_contents ($filename, $rowstr2, FILE_APPEND);
 }//end while
}
else {
  echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why have any PHP code?

Given this query:

```
SELECT  province, city, population
    INTO  OUTFILE '/tmp/xx.txt' COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
    FROM  canada
    WHERE  population > 0
    LIMIT  11;
```

It generates the file `xx.txt`:

```
"Alberta"|"Killam"|1056
"Alberta"|"Smoky Lake"|1063
"Alberta"|"Irricana"|1091
"Alberta"|"Viking"|1106
"Alberta"|"Two Hills"|1147
"Alberta"|"Spirit River"|1157
"Alberta"|"Bassano"|1388
"Alberta"|"Clairmont"|1483
"Alberta"|"Elk Point"|1514
"Alberta"|"Wembley"|1574
"Alberta"|"Bon Accord"|1611
```

Meanwhile, in your code, `if (...num_rows>0)` is redundant because `while(...)` will do nothing if there are no rows.  Removing the `if` will *happen to* fix the bug.  The bug is `result` instead of `$result`.

Comment: Given the last field has data separated by commas, which need to be changed into pipes and the need to dynamically calculate out 26 total pipes per row, I didn't think there was a way of doing this strictly in SQL.

Comment: I have edited the original question to include the PHP I'm working with, I hope that clarifies what I am trying to do.  I don't believe I have the PHP quite correct though.

Comment: @Alohajoe5 - What do you get in the file when you run that PHP?

Comment: I get: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) on line 13

Comment: I fixed the syntax error and now I'm getting another error: "uncaught error: call to a member function query() on null in /path/to/my/file/file.php:12  Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /path/to/my/file/file.php on line 12

Comment: Doing research I'm not sure if this issue is related to the $conn variable definition or something else.

Comment: @Alohajoe5 - What is on line 13 (and the lines before and after)?

Comment: the problem is actually on line 12:

11 $sql = "SELECT * FROM my_view";
12 $result = $conn->query($sql);
13 if ($result->num_rows > 0){
14  while ($row = $result-?fetch_assoc()){

Comment: I now get: "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in var/www/html/my_php.php:11 Stack Trace: #0 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/my_php.php line 11.  Is this, perhaps because of how I'm invoking the query?  https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1174904/Fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-query-on-nul

Comment: @Alohajoe5 - That says that the _connection_ failed.

Comment: I have fixed the connection error and now I get an error file named signalsdat that contains only one row that says:  Array$|$|$|$|$| (the correct 26 number of times, but no data from the query)

Comment: The presence of "Array" implies that you have an array where a scalar is needed, or a 2D array where a 1D array is needed.

Comment: I get 2 warnings: "Warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/www/html/my_php.php on line 20 PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in myphp.php on line 26" and Notice Array to string conversion in myphp.php on line 26 PHP warning: substr_count() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in myphp on line 20.  I will work on correcting this.

Comment: I can't help without having numbered lines of PHP code.  Maybe you can figure it out yourself?

Comment: I've got it resolved.  Thanks for the help--this was my first question.  Tried to not get it downvoted but whatever.  Thank you again for your time.